# Python sqlalchemy large file issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm having problem using the following code to load a large(23,000 records, 10 fields) airport code csv file into a database with sqlalchemy:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, Date, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def Load_Data(file_name):
    f = lambda s: str(s)
    data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, converters={0: f, 1:f, 2:f, 6:f, 7:f, 8:f, 9:f, 10:f})
    return data.tolist()

Base = declarative_base()

class AirportCode(Base):
    #Tell SQLAlchemy what the table name is and if there's any table-specific arguments it should know about
    __tablename__ = 'AirportCode'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    #tell SQLAlchemy the name of column and its attributes:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    ident = Column(String)
    type = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    latitude_deg = Column(String)
    longitude_deg = Column(String)
    elevation_ft = Column(String)
    continent = Column(String)
    iso_country = Column(String)
    iso_region = Column(String)
    municipality = Column(String)
    gps_code = Column(String)


    def __repr__(self):
        #return "<AirportCode(name='%s', municipality='%s')>\n" % (self.name, self.municipality)
        return "name:{} municipality:{}\n".format(self.name, self.municipality)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = time()

    #Create the database
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///airport-codes.db')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    #Create the session
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    s = session()


    records_to_commit = 0
    file_name = "airport-codes.csv"       #23,000 records fails at next line
    #file_name = "airport-codes.alaska      250 records works fine" 
    print file_name #for debugging
    data = Load_Data(file_name)  # fails here on large files and triggers the except: below
    print 'file loaded' #for debugging

    for i in data:
        records_to_commit += 1


        record = AirportCode(**{

            'ident' : i[0].lower(),
            'type' : i[1].lower(),  
            'name' : i[2].lower(), 
            'latitude_deg' : i[3], 
            'longitude_deg' : i[4], 
            'elevation_ft' : i[5], 
            'continent' : i[6], 
            'iso_country' : i[7], 
            'iso_region' : i[8], 
            'municipality' : i[9].lower(), 
            'gps_code' : i[10].lower() 


        })

        s.add(record) #Add all the records

        #if records_to_commit == 1000:
            #s.flush() #Attempt to commit batch of 1000 records
            #records_to_commit = 0
    s.commit() # flushes everything remaining + commits

    s.close() #Close the connection
    print "Time elapsed: " + str(time() - t) + " s."
```

I adapted this code from another post on this forum and it works fine if I use a subset of the main csv file (Alaska airports) that is only 250 records.

When I try the entire data base of 23,000 records the program fails to load at this line in the code:

```
data = Load_Data(file_name)
```

I am working on a raspberry pi 3

Comment: How does it fail? you're masking errors there with your bare `try/except`... remove those and get a proper traceback - do an `except Exception as e: print e` for instance - I'm guessing you're getting an AttributeError/TypeError  on trying to insert some rows that doesn't occur in the test data.

Comment: Please fix your identation - you probably didn't use the button "{}" in formatting and just idented the lines at row 0 so everything showed up as code. But this is invalid Python

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments.  Removing try/except revealed the issues.  There were many international characters, extra commas within fields, and special characters, etc that caused the issue when loading the file.  The Alaska airport entries were error free so it loaded fine.

Database now loads 22,000 records in 32 seconds.  I deleted about 1000 entries since they were foreign entries and I want this be a US airport directory